# Sqlite database migration issue caused by Locale dependant table names

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, database-migration, ormlite

My question is about how to fix the problem we faced in a way that works for both existing Sqlite databases (users who update their app) as well as preventing it from happening in the future.

**Problem**
We are using OrmLite in our Android application, the way we are creating our tables is that we are using the OrmLite annotation `@DatabaseTable` on our models.

Digging deeper into OrmLite source code, found that `DatabaseTableConfig.extractTableName` method does that to get the table name if you don't specify it as param to the annotation

```
clazz.getSimpleName().toLowerCase()
```

And looking in the source code of `String` found that it does this

```
toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
```

And for some languages that call to toLowerCase() actually changes the table name (which in this case is the class name)

So for example, if we have a table named `info` the table name can be turned into `ınfo`

Now consider this scenario

- A user has non-english Locale on their phone, when that table is
  created it is called `ınfo`
- The user changed the locale to english
- The user upgrade the app, and onUpgrade is called, we try to ALTER
  the table `info` but we cannot find it, because it actually is called
  `ınfo`

The only solution that comes to mind

- Force toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH) for all users
- When we run into a case where we cannot find a table onUpgrade we
  drop that table and re-create it

This has a downside of losing the locally stored info of the user

My question is, does anyone have a suggestion that will be forward/backward compatible where we don't lose the old data?

Note: I don't know how many locale's change the english letters into something else, so basically I cannot know which locale was the old one to try "guessing" the old table name and migrating data from it

Answer (score 0):

Well only thing I could think of is to use a query like this:

```
"SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table'"
```

to get all the table names in DB.

You can use it in some sort of update/rebuild utility for users db and just try to match table names from english locale to something inside table names set.

Once you will find a match you can fix the name using eg:

```
"ALTER TABLE old_name RENAME TO new_name"
```

It's hard to give you some straight idea of matching method but you can check if:

```
("ınfo".toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH)).toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH).equals("info")
```

This "ı" character issue is well known and appears eg when using Turkish locale and as far as I know

```
"ı".toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH).equals("I")
```

and

```
"I".toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH).equals("i")
```

So there is a chance for this double conversion I posted.

Comment: I need to try that, but it will be quite tricky, there are lots of tables / their fields as well :(

Comment: Well this tool will work automaticaly. You just have to iterate through list of tables/fields and you are meant to do this once after update. But another solution is to change ORM or to override its implementation forceing double conversion.